# grpc-java: Server side can't get exception from client side onError

Tags: grpc-java

in Bidirectional streaming RPC.

Client side call outbound StreamObserver.onError:

```java
        @Override
        public void onNext(@NonNull ActionReq req) {
            String actionId = req.getId();
            String actionName = req.getName();
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("onNext: id:%s,name:%s", actionId, actionName));
            if (!mActionId.equals(actionId)) {
                Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                metadata.put(GrpcKeyUtil.sMetaActorActionIdKey, mActionId);
                StatusRuntimeException e = Status.INVALID_ARGUMENT
                        .withDescription("actionId is error! stream.id:" + mActionId + ",req.id:" + actionId)
                        .asRuntimeException(metadata);
                // the mPeer is Client side outbound StreamObserver!
                mPeer.onError(e);
                return;
            }
            // ...
        }
```

Server side receives error from inbound StreamObserver.onError:

```java
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: ", t);
            if (t instanceof StatusRuntimeException e) {
                Metadata metadata = e.getTrailers();
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: metadata " + metadata);
            }
            actionResult.onError(t);
        }
```

The problem is that the server side onError received `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: client canceled`.

That is to say, what the server receives is not `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: actionId is error!`

the client side log:

```
  614423: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: Cancelled by client with StreamObserver.onError()
  614424: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:539)
  614425: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:487)
  614426: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
  614427: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
  614428: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
  614429: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
  614430: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
  614431: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
  614432: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:567)
  614433: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:71)
  614434: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:735)
  614435: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:716)
  614436: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
  614437: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
  614438: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  614439: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  614440: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
  614441: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream: Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: actionId is error! stream.id:e7603444-f9d8-4597-9525-7f1bd4fccbb6,req.id:
  614442: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:539)
  614443: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at agent.grpc.client.ActorChannelMgr$ActorActionStream.onNext(ActorChannelMgr.java:110)
  614444: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at agent.grpc.client.ActorChannelMgr$ActorActionStream.onNext(ActorChannelMgr.java:86)
  614445: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onMessage(ClientCalls.java:474)
  614446: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
  614447: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
  614448: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:660)
  614449: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:647)
  614450: 08-19 19:38:26.205 27030 27066 E ActorActionStream:   ... 5 more
```

the server side log:

```
  614454: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream: onError: 
  614455: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: client cancelled
  614456: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:530)
  614457: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler$StreamingServerCallListener.onCancel(ServerCalls.java:291)
  614458: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onCancel(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
  614459: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onCancel(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
  614460: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onCancel(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
  614461: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.closedInternal(ServerCallImpl.java:365)
  614462: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.closed(ServerCallImpl.java:354)
  614463: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1Closed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:909)
  614464: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
  614465: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
  614466: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  614467: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  614468: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 E ActorActionStream:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
  614469: 08-19 19:38:26.208 25243 27100 D ActorActionStream: onError: metadata null
```

I want to know how the server can correctly receive `INVALID_ARGUMENT: actionId is error!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as designed. Note that in the client-server model, the server can return an error which the underlying system (gRPC in this case) will transport and make available to the client.

Although the `onError` method is available to the client's outbound requestObserver (request stream) it is only used to cancel the stream (and the RPC) because a client is not supposed to return/send error to the server and there is no mechanism to do it.